# Есть ли в этом предложениии пояснение?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли здесь двоеточие?

Он прошел большой путь от рядового инженера до директора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависит от произнесения фразы, от паузы.

Он прошел большой путь от рядового инженера до директора. - исходная классическая фраза без пояснительной паузы.

Он прошел большой путь, от рядового инженера до директора. - с паузой уточнения.

Он прошел большой путь - от рядового инженера до директора. - с паузой пояснения.

Двоеточие ставится в  бессоюзном сложном предложении, здесь - простое. Двоеточие возможно как авторский знак, сейчас признаётся вариативная замена тире-двоеточие, потому что можно вставить А ИМЕННО, что-то вроде синонимии значений простого и сложного предложений.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: Двоеточие объясняется именно тем, как сказала Людмила, что здесь можно вставить "а именно".

Answer (score 1):

При постанове знаков препинания следует исходить из семантики сообщения, а семантика здесь пояснительная, так как раскрывается значение слова "большой". Таким образом, мы имеем согласованное и несогласованное определения, связанные пояснительными отношениями.

Вариант 1.  Он прошел большой, от рядового инженера до директора, путь (пояснение).Он прошел большой путь, от рядового инженера до директора (пояснение).

Вариант 2. Он прошел большой путь - от рядового инженера до директора (пояснение в присоединительном варианте).

Вариант 3. Он прошел большой путь,  а именно от рядового инженера до директора. Сравнить: "Случилось очень важное для них обоих событие, именно встреча Кити с Вронским".

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1. Двоеточие и отсутствие знаков - нежелательны, грамматически их сложно объяснить.
2. Интонация в данном случае должна подтверждать грамматику, а не являться решением задачи.
3. Подстановка "а именно" - это только прием, позволяющий определить пояснительный характер отношений, но это не повод для выбора двоеточия. В теме "Уточняющие, пояснительные и присоединительные члены предложения с бессоюзной связью" двоеточие не применяется - только запятая и тире.

Comment: София, Вы, как всегда, категоричны. Семантику сообщения знает автор. И если он не поставил знаков препинания, значит, он не вносил никакого пояснительного смысла. Это вполне объяснимо, я бы тоже ничего не поставила, фраза без запятых вполне корректна. Ваш первый вариант - переделанная фраза, а запятая как раз объясняется уточняющим или пояснительным значением, чаще всего в этом случае ставится запятая, тире здесь предпочтительно (если хочется выделить пояснение), потому что пояснение стоит в конце предложения.

Comment: Между двумя определениями, отнесенными к одному предмету,могут быть следующие отношения: однородные, неоднородные, уточняюще-пояснительные, присоединительные. При отсутствии знаков мы имеем неоднородные отношения, которые будут обозначать "путь о инженера до директора", который дополнительно определяется как большой, что странно (или  средний/маленький?). Можно сказать: он прошел сложный путь от рядового инженера до директора. Здесь будет авторская оценка этого пути, определения неоднородные.

Comment: Все они [письма] о главном: перестройке в нашей жизни (газ.); Настроение одно: скорее добраться до дома (газ.). (Примеры взяты из (http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123)[полного академического справочника]

Comment: Тире - основной знак,  двоеточие ДОПУСКАЕТСЯ как исключение: а) при подчеркнутом пояснении ("Все они о главном: перестройке в нашей жизни". Обратим внимание на отсутствие второго предлога; б) встречается постановка двоеточия при пояснительном члене предложения, чтобы избежать двух тире: "Предложен и другой путь: использование некоторых видов морских растений – водорослей, богатых многими ценными веществами".

Answer (score 0):

Двоеточие нужно, т.к. здесь пояснение.